# Fitness probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Tomorrow I'm going to get in shape. On day $1$, I'm going to run $12$ laps on the track. Then for each of the next six days, I'm going to roll a six-sided die, and then run that many more laps than I ran the previous day. (Example sequence: $12, 14, 20, 25, 28, 29, 33$). How many different possible $7$-day sequences of this form are there?

I'm not sure if I have the correct answer but I thought the answer was $1\cdot6^6$ because $12$ is always the first day, then you have $6$ following days where each day has $6$ possible numbers you can roll. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Looks good to me as well.

Comment: Great thanks so much!